# Check if each values are in different arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I need to check if element 'a' is present twice, 'b' is present twice and 'c' is present once in a group of arrays. Each element should be in five different arrays.

That is like, 'a' in array1, another 'a' in array2, 'b' in array3, another 'b' in array4 and 'c' in array5. there should be atleast five or more arrays and each element should be in different arrays using php. Now my code is

```
$arr = array(
    $branch1 = array('a', 'b'),
    $branch2 = array('b','c'),
    $branch3 = array('a',  'c'),
    $branch4 = array('c', 'a'),
    $branch5 = array('b', 'a'),
    $branch6 = array('b', 'c', 'a')
    );//This may have any number of branches and any kind of combinations of a, b and c(but each element only once in each array). 

$reqd_branch_count = 5;//required branch count
```

As I am new to php, now I have written a very long code, but it fails when trying new combinations.Please help me if someone knows.

---

From asker's comment:

> The condition is a user has some ranks in his/her downline which are
> in branches. for example rank1, rank2 and rank3,.... Those rank counts
> are shown in that array. If that user need to get rank8 he/she should
> have one rank 7, two rank 5 or 7s, and two rank4s, that should be
> 1+2+2=5 branches, that is each rank should be in different branches.
> Hope you understood the question

Comment: *I tried a lot... But failed* what have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried? It will help others to understand your problem better and write good answers

Comment: I didn't get it as array.. but need the logic to solve, if i get those values in an array

Comment: The condition you described here is too confusing, AND is having priority or OR ?

Comment: Please try to specify that "condition" more precise. I currently do not really know what would be accepted and what not.

Comment: I will update the question

Comment: The example does not satisfy ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the condition to check is whether each element is in different branches and the count is satisfied

Comment: Or I need to return the total number of branches if each element is considered in different branches

Comment: Untill you exactly describe the condition, maybe with some examples, i think we not able to help :(

Comment: Lets solve the problem step by step. Does my condition for totla amount correct?

Comment: The condition is a user has some ranks in his/her downline which are in branches. for example rank1, rank2 and rank3,.... Those rank counts are shown in that array. If that user need to get rank8 he/she should have one rank 7, two  rank 5 or 7s, and two rank4s, that should be 1+2+2=5 branches, that is each rank should be in different branches. Hope you understood the question

Comment: Yes, your answer was correct, what i need is not the total count, count as if each element in each array

Comment: "Each element should be in five different arrays." So if `$branch1 = array('a','b','c')` and `$branch2 = array('a','b')`, that's not good enough? If I've understood you right, then that complicates things, and we need to think more deeply about what algorithm to use. You could use Hall's Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem . You'd have to check that at least 5 arrays contain `a`, `b` or `c`; that at least 3 contain `b` and `c`; and several similar conditions. Alternatively, you could try to actually find 2 arrays for `a`, etc.

Comment: I find this question to be VERY Unclear and I have voted to close accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly

merge all arrays, count amount of all items in all arrays and test you want

```
$arr = array_merge($branch1,$branch2,$branch3,$branch4,$branch5,$branch6);
$count = array_count_values($arr);

echo $count[7]; // 4
echo $count[4]; // 2
```

so, yuo can make condition

```
if (($count[7] == 1)  or ($count[7] == 2) or ($count[5] == 2) or ($count[4] == 2))  
   {  any stuff for true}
```

**UPDATE**

```
$arr = array(
$branch1=array('3'),
$branch2=array('4'),
$branch3=array('3','5','7'),
$branch4=array('3','4','7'),
$branch5=array('7'),
$branch6=array('4','7'));
// find rank per branch
$ranks = array_map('max', $arr);
// make array rank => amount
$count = array_replace(array_fill(0,7,0), array_count_values($ranks));

if (($count[7] >= 1) and (($count[7] + $count[5]) >= 2) and (($count[7] + $count[5] + $count[4]) >= 5)) { 
     echo "Satisfy ";
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question once more. Please check and help if possible

Comment: @Aparna Look my another answer

Answer (score 0):

Because it is another question, this is another answer

```
$arr = array(
    $branch1 = array('a'),
    $branch2 = array('b','c'),
    $branch3 = array('a',  'c'),
    $branch4 = array('c', 'a'),
    $branch5 = array('a'),
    $branch6 = array( 'c', 'a')
    );

$names = array('a', 'b', 'c');    // for convenience only 
var_dump(goNext($arr, $names));   // watch result

function goNext($arr, $names) {
    // for each name make array with list of brances where it is
    $in = array(array(), array(), array());
    foreach($arr as $k1 => $branch) 
        foreach($names as $k2 => $letter)
            if(in_array($letter, $branch)) $in[$k2][] = $k1;

    foreach ($in[0] as $i1)  // 1st a
        foreach (array_diff($in[0], array($i1)) as $i2)   // 2nd a
            foreach (array_diff($in[1], array($i1,$i2)) as $i3)  // 1st b
                foreach (array_diff($in[1], array($i1,$i2,$i3)) as $i4)  // 2nd b
                    foreach(array_diff($in[2], array($i1,$i2,$i3,$i4)) as $i5) {
                        // if here we find combination we need
                        // next line only for debug
                        // it shows set of branches that give true
                        //    a           a           b           b           c
                        echo $i1 . " " . $i2 . " " . $i3 . " " . $i4 . " " . $i5;
                        return(true);
                    }
    return(false);   // combination has not found
}
```